# Adding a condition to Linker Command File

Tags: linker, powerpc, linker-scripts

Can i write a condition in the .lcf ?

I want to check if the sum of certain sections is above a certain threshold. if yes i want the linker to show Error/Warning

I'm new to the .lcf and i don't know if this is possible or not.

Any Advice ?

Linker : WindRiver Linker 5.9.4

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. But unless you give all required information it is impossible to say. For instance: are you aware there is not a single linker on the market? And that's no way related to the C language.

Comment: it is WindRiver Diab linker

Answer (score 0):

The following line if added to the `.lcf` will give a linker error if the `value` is above the `threshold`:

```
ASSERT( value < threshold, " The value is above the threshold ")
```